# PHP Nusoap - SOAP Request not working

Tags: php, web-services, nusoap

Hello i am very new to webservice, in php with below code i am trying to make soap request as shown in below XML, but it says Error

> HTTP Error: Unsupported HTTP response status 405 Method Not Allowed (soapclient->response has contents of the response)

Questions:

1. How to pass headers?
2. How to pass FetchCalendarRequest with request like in XML?

I have used Nusoap here but if you have a SOAP PHP class solution it is also invited.

My code:

```
<?php

require_once('../lib/nusoap.php');

$client = new nusoap_client("http://webservices.test.com/ows/5.1/Availability.wsdl");
$err    = $client->getError();

if ($err)
{
    client_debug_error_message('Constructor error', $err, $client);
    exit;
}

// Call the SOAP method
$result = $client->call(
    'FetchCalendar', 
    array(
        'StayDateRange' => array(
            'StartDate' => '2013-10-01', 
            'EndDate'   => '2013-10-10',
        ),
    ),
);

// Check for a fault
if ($client->fault) 
{
    debug_preformatted('Fault', $result);
} 
else 
{
    // Check for errors
    $err = $client->getError();

    if ($err) 
    {
        debug_preformatted('Error', $err);
    }
    else 
    {
        debug_preformatted('Result', $result);
    }
}

// Display the request and response
client_debug_dump($client);
```

**XML**  :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Header>
    <OGHeader transactionID="005435" timeStamp="2008-12-09T13:26:56.4056250-05:00" xmlns="http://webservices.test.com/og/4.3/Core/">
      <Origin entityID="OWS" systemType="WEB" />
      <Destination entityID="WEST" systemType="ORS" />
    </OGHeader>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <FetchCalendarRequest xmlns:a="http://webservices.test.com/og/4.3/Availability/" xmlns:hc="http://webservices.test.com/og/4.3/HotelCommon/" xmlns="http://webservices.test.com/ows/5.1/Availability.wsdl">
      <HotelReference chainCode="AXA" hotelCode="AXAMUM" />
      <StayDateRange>
        <hc:StartDate>2013-10-01</hc:StartDate>
        <hc:EndDate>2013-10-10</hc:EndDate>
      </StayDateRange>
      <GuestCount>
        <hc:GuestCount ageQualifyingCode="ADULT" count="1" />
        <hc:GuestCount ageQualifyingCode="CHILD" count="0" />
      </GuestCount>
    </FetchCalendarRequest>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>


    Post Url :http://000.000.000.00:8080/ows_ws_51/Availability.asmx 
Soap Action :  http://webservices.test.com/ows/5.1/Availability.wsdl#FetchCalendar
```

*Edit:* **Working Solution 16 Sep 2013**

This solution is with Soap PHP Class only I want it to work with Nusoap bow.

```
<?php

$wsdl   = "http://###.###.###.##:8080/ows_ws_51/Availability.asmx?wsdl"; 
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array(  'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,'trace' => true,)); 

//=========== Header Setting ============

$ns                         = 'http://webservices.micros.com/og/4.3/Availability/'; //Namespace of the WS.//Body of the Soap Header.
$strHeaderComponent_Session = <<<XML
<OGHeader transactionID="005435" timeStamp="2008-12-09T13:26:56.4056250-05:00" xmlns="http://webservices.micros.com/og/4.3/Core/">
  <Origin entityID="OWS" systemType="WEB" />
  <Destination entityID="WEST" systemType="ORS" />
</OGHeader>
XML;
$objVar_Session_Inside      = new SoapVar($strHeaderComponent_Session, XSD_ANYXML, null, null, null);
$objHeader_Session_Outside  = new SoapHeader($ns , 'SessionHeader', $objVar_Session_Inside);

// More than one header can be provided in this array.
$client->__setSoapHeaders(array($objHeader_Session_Outside));

//============== Request ================

$xml = <<<XML
<FetchCalendarRequest xmlns:a="http://webservices.micros.com/og/4.3/Availability/" xmlns:hc="http://webservices.micros.com/og/4.3/HotelCommon/" xmlns="http://webservices.micros.com/ows/5.1/Availability.wsdl">
  <HotelReference chainCode="AXA" hotelCode="{$DdlHotels}" />
  <StayDateRange>
    <hc:StartDate>{$Arrive}</hc:StartDate>
    <hc:EndDate>{$Depart}</hc:EndDate>
  </StayDateRange>
  <GuestCount>
    <hc:GuestCount ageQualifyingCode="ADULT" count="1" />
    <hc:GuestCount ageQualifyingCode="CHILD" count="0" />
  </GuestCount>
</FetchCalendarRequest>
XML;

$args = array(new SoapVar($xml, XSD_ANYXML));

try 
{

    $response = $client->__soapCall( 'FetchCalendar', $args );
}
catch (SoapFault $e) 
{
    echo "Error: {$e}"; exit;
}
```

Comment: If you paste example code, take care it is properly intended, readable and it does not contain dead or unnecessary debug code - but more ideally being a fully self-contained working example. See my edit. Also Stackoverflow works better if you ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use PHP's built in SOAP library to create a SOAP client and call a method from the WSDL, try something like this:

```
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array(  'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
                                        'trace' => true,
                                        )); 
try {
$params = array(
         //Your parameters here
          );    
$res = $client->__soapCall( 'SoapMethod', $params );
return $res;
} catch (SoapFault $e) {
echo "Error: {$e}";
}

//for debugging what the outgoing xml looks like
$client->__getLastRequest();
```

The WSDL should help structure the xml for your params. If you cannot get that to work the way you want you could try passing the xml yourself using [SoapVar() and setting the encode to XSD_ANYXML.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18723216/how-to-build-a-correct-soap-request-with-php/18725930#18725930)

[If you also need to add additional header information take a look at this example from the PHP docs.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapheader.php#107889)

Comment: with your links i got the solution for Soap PHP Class(`'check ans edited'`), i want Solution with Nusoap. for which the boundary is.

Comment: @BhavinRana: Well your question says different: *"i have used nusoap here but if u have soap php class solution is also invited."* and that has been given here, you say you got it working due to the resources given, so you perhaps should consider for your *next* question what *exactly* you want to ask about *programming wise*.

Answer (score 1):

```
$params = array(//your params as specified by documentation);
$result = $client->call(array("Availability"=>$params));
```

Comment: thanks for ans. can you tell me what r the Parameters in this XML file ? i cant iden.how can i pass it with hira. array ?

Comment: these are your parmeters which you need to pass.

Comment: i tried $result = $client->call("Availability", array("StartDate" => "2012-04-11T11:00:00.000Z","EndDate" => "2012-04-12T11:00:00.000Z")); but it says HTTP Error: Unsupported HTTP response status 405 Method Not Allowed (soapclient->response has contents of the response)

Comment: please try $result = $client->call(array("Availability"=> array("StartDate" => "2012-04-11T11:00:00.000Z","EndDate" => "2012-04-12T11:00:00.000Z")));

Comment: now it says Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\nusoap-0.9.5\lib\nusoap.php on line 7325

Answer (score 1):

Might I suggest trying to learn SOAP with a different example web service. The wsdl document published for this service appears to be incomplete, as they have entered the incorrect SOAP address for the Availability service. With an incorrect or incomplete WSDL document, the SOAP library you are using will not be able to form a valid SOAP request and send it to the correct endpoint.

```
<wsdl:service name="AvailabilityService">
    <wsdl:port name="AvailabilityPort" binding="tns:AvailabilityBinding">
        <soap:address location="http://tempuri.org"/>
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

As you can see, the AvailabilityService endpoint is described as http://tempuri.org, which is explained as a default test namespace [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tempuri).

In your original post, you have the 'POST URL' described as `http://000.000.000.00:8080/ows_ws_51/Availability.asmx`. How is anyone supposed to try the example, if you list the 'POST URL' an as obviously invalid URL.

You have also listed the WSDL document as http://webservices.test.com/ows/5.1/Availability.wsdl, which is also an invalid URL.

Here is a PHP example, accessing a valid WSDL document, using PHP's built-in SOAP library, which can be enabled by enabling the php_soap.dll extension in your php.ini file.

```
<?php

    $wsdl = "http://www.restfulwebservices.net/wcf/StockQuoteService.svc?wsdl";

    $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array(
        "trace"      => 1,
        "exceptions" => 0));

    $parameters = array("request" => "IBM");

    $value = $client->GetStockQuote($parameters);

    $json = json_encode($value);

    echo $json;
```

Comment: i have not given actual URLs for security reason. but can say 000 is the IP, and test.com is some domain.

Answer (score 0):

> ***Note:*** The following is more of a comment than an answer. I leave it here for further reference as it would not fit into a comment box and it references existing Q&A possible worth for future visitors

You ask two questions regarding Nusoap here:

> 1. How to pass headers?
> 2. How to pass FetchCalendarRequest with request like in XML?

The first one *How to pass headers?* has been outlined already in this Q&A:

- [NuSoap PHP webservice with soap headers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7705787/367456)

As you have not written specifically in your question what of this (and possible other of the) existing Q&A didn't work for you, this might not suit your needs but you need to give detailed feedback first I'd say.

The second question *How to pass FetchCalendarRequest with request like in XML?* you probably mean how to call a SOAP action or method ("Request") that has been named in a WSDL. This has already been covered as well for Nusoap on the Stackoverflow website:

- [Nusoap use existing WSDL how to?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8316743/367456)

As you have not written specifically in your question what of this (and possible other of the) existing Q&A didn't work for you, this might not suit your needs but you need to give detailed feedback first I'd say to turn this into a concrete programming question.

BTW Stackoverflow works best by asking one question at a time.