# PHP SOAP Request not working

Tags: php, soap

Hello i am very new to webservice, in php with below code i am trying to make soap request as shown in below XML, but it says 
**Error**

HTTP Error: Unsupported HTTP response status 405 Method Not Allowed (soapclient->response has contents of the response)

Q.
1)how to pass headers 
2)how to pass FetchCalendarRequest

i have used nusoap here but if u have soap php class solution is also invited.

```
    <?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL);


   require("../lib/nusoap.php");

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
$ERROR_MSG = '';

$s_WSPROTOCOL = 'http';
$s_WSHOSTNAME = '###.###.###.##';
$s_WSPORT = ':8080';
$s_WSPATHNAME = 'ows_ws_51/Availability.asmx?WSDL';         
$s_WSTIPOOP = 'FetchCalendar';

$parameters['StayDateRange'] = array('StartDate' => '2013-10-01','EndDate' => '2013-10-10');


echo $s_WSTIPOOP."<br />";
echo $s_WSPROTOCOL."://".$s_WSHOSTNAME.$s_WSPORT."/".$s_WSPATHNAME."<br /><br /><br />";     
$client = new nusoap_client($s_WSPROTOCOL."://".$s_WSHOSTNAME.$s_WSPORT."/".$s_WSPATHNAME, true);

$result = $client->call($s_WSTIPOOP, $parameters);

if ($client->fault) {

echo '<h2>Fault (Expect - The request contains an invalid SOAP body)</h2><pre>'; 
print_r($result); echo '</pre>';

} else {

$err = $client->getError();
if ($err) {

echo '<h2>Error</h2><pre>' . $err . '</pre>';

} else {
echo '<h2>Result</h2><pre>'; print_r($result); echo '</pre>';
}
}

echo '<h2>Request</h2><pre>' . htmlspecialchars($client->request, ENT_QUOTES) . '</pre>';
echo '<h2>Response</h2><pre>' . htmlspecialchars($client->response, ENT_QUOTES) . '</pre>';
echo '<h2>Debug</h2><pre>' . htmlspecialchars($client->getDebug(), ENT_QUOTES) . '</pre>';

    ?>
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Header>
    <OGHeader transactionID="005435" timeStamp="2008-12-09T13:26:56.4056250-05:00" xmlns="http://webservices.test.com/og/4.3/Core/">
      <Origin entityID="OWS" systemType="WEB" />
      <Destination entityID="WEST" systemType="ORS" />
    </OGHeader>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <FetchCalendarRequest xmlns:a="http://webservices.test.com/og/4.3/Availability/" xmlns:hc="http://webservices.test.com/og/4.3/HotelCommon/" xmlns="http://webservices.test.com/ows/5.1/Availability.wsdl">
      <HotelReference chainCode="AXA" hotelCode="AXAMUM" />
      <StayDateRange>
        <hc:StartDate>2013-10-01</hc:StartDate>
        <hc:EndDate>2013-10-10</hc:EndDate>
      </StayDateRange>
      <GuestCount>
        <hc:GuestCount ageQualifyingCode="ADULT" count="1" />
        <hc:GuestCount ageQualifyingCode="CHILD" count="0" />
      </GuestCount>
    </FetchCalendarRequest>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>


    Post Url :http://000.000.000.00:8080/ows_ws_51/Availability.asmx 
Soap Action :  http://webservices.test.com/ows/5.1/Availability.wsdl#FetchCalendar
```

Comment: Possible related (same webservice): [PHP Nusoap - SOAP Request not working](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18125751/367456)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you don't have to send credentials, this returns a answere:

```
<?php
$soap = new SoapClient('http://webservices.micros.com/ows/5.1/Availability.wsdl', array("trace" => 1, "exception" => 0));

var_dump($soap->FetchCalendar(array(
    'StayDateRange' => array(
        'StartDate' => '2013-10-01',
        'EndDate' => '2013-10-10'
    )
)));
```

It still needs a `HotelReference` tough.

===

**Here is how to set SoapHeaders:**

```
<?php
$headerbody = array('Origin' => 'foo',
                    'Destination' => 'bar');
$header = new SOAPHeader($ns, 'RequestorCredentials', $headerbody);
$soap->__setSoapHeaders($header);
```

More on the subject can be found: http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.setsoapheaders.php

===

Here is the soapui response when you want to perform that method

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:core="http://webservices.micros.com/og/4.3/Core/" xmlns:ava="http://webservices.micros.com/ows/5.1/Availability.wsdl" xmlns:hot="http://webservices.micros.com/og/4.3/HotelCommon/">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <core:OGHeader transactionID="?" authToken="?" timeStamp="?" primaryLangID="E" channelValidation="true" terminalID="?">
         <core:Origin entityID="?" organizationID="?" systemType="?"/>
         <core:Destination entityID="?" organizationID="?" systemType="?"/>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <core:Intermediaries>
            <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
            <core:EndPoint entityID="?" organizationID="?" systemType="?"/>
         </core:Intermediaries>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <core:Authentication>
            <core:UserCredentials>
               <core:UserName>?</core:UserName>
               <core:UserPassword>?</core:UserPassword>
               <core:Domain>?</core:Domain>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <core:SecurityId>?</core:SecurityId>
            </core:UserCredentials>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <core:Licence>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <core:Key>?</core:Key>
            </core:Licence>
         </core:Authentication>
      </core:OGHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ava:FetchCalendarRequest>
         <ava:HotelReference chainCode="?" hotelCode="?">?</ava:HotelReference>
         <ava:StayDateRange>
            <hot:StartDate>?</hot:StartDate>
            <!--You have a CHOICE of the next 2 items at this level-->
            <hot:EndDate>?</hot:EndDate>
            <hot:Duration>?</hot:Duration>
         </ava:StayDateRange>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ava:GuestCount isPerRoom="?">
            <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
            <hot:GuestCount ageQualifyingCode="?" otherAgeQualifyingCode="?" age="?" count="?"/>
         </ava:GuestCount>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ava:RatePlanCode>?</ava:RatePlanCode>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ava:RoomTypeCode>?</ava:RoomTypeCode>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ava:BlockCode>?</ava:BlockCode>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ava:CorporateCode>?</ava:CorporateCode>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ava:PromotionCode>?</ava:PromotionCode>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ava:NumberOfNights>?</ava:NumberOfNights>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ava:RestrictedMode>?</ava:RestrictedMode>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ava:InventoryMode>?</ava:InventoryMode>
      </ava:FetchCalendarRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

If i compare it to your settings, the options you send with the response you do not provide the UserCredentials. And that gives me the feeling you get the error that you are not allowed to use that method. Start with providing your credentials.

Comment: can you show me a sample code how you have passed this header ?

Comment: Undefined variable: ns

Comment: $ns is the namespace, i think you will need the `http://webservices.micros.com/og/4.3/Availability/` namespace. Looking in the wsdl `<xs:import namespace="http://webservices.micros.com/og/4.3/Availability/" schemaLocation="../../og/4.3/Availability.xsd"/>`

Comment: i have changed my code, its shows now ,`Error

Charset from HTTP Content-Type 'UTF-8' does not match encoding from XML declaration 'iso-8859-1'`

Comment: Try: $soap = new SoapClient('http://webservices.micros.com/ows/5.1/Availability.wsdl', array("trace" => 1, "exception" => 0, "encoding" => 'iso-8859-1'));

Comment: Seriously? I have pointed you in the right direction, in your question you stated that nu_soap is not a requirement. I have answered two questions already. Please do some investigation as well. If my responses have helped you, accept as answere, and create new issues for new questions.

Comment: +1ed, if u see XML, `<HotelReference chainCode="LEELA" hotelCode="LEELAMUM" />` Property we need to send , can you tell me how to send it ? other parameter i have sent.

Comment: Current Status of Q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18735748/uncaught-soapfault-exception-http-bad-request