# Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Bad Request

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

i am trying to make a Soap request i says this error :

> Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Bad Request in C:\

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient(null, array('location' => "http://webservices.micros.com/ows/5.1/Availability.wsdl#FetchCalendar",
                                     'uri'      => "http://###.###.###.##:8080/ows_ws_51/Availability.asmx?wsdl"));

//print_r($client);

$para = array('StayDateRange' => array('StartDate' => '2013-10-01','EndDate' => '2013-10-10'),'GuestCount'=>array('GuestCountageQualifyingCode'=>'ADULT','GuestCountageQualifyingCode'=>'CHILD'));


$ns = 'http://webservices.micros.com/og/4.3/Availability/'; //Namespace of the WS.
//Body of the Soap Header.
$headerbody = array('OriginentityID' => 'OWS',
                    'DestinationentityID' => 'WEST',
                    'systemType'=>'WEB',
                      'systemType'=>'ORS');
//Create Soap Header.       
$header = new SOAPHeader($ns, 'OGHeader', $headerbody);       
//set the Headers of Soap Client.
$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);

$client->__soapCall("FetchCalendar", $para);


?>
```

whats wrong in my code ?

after adding Exception handling : 
http://postimg.org/image/6w9lmac1d/

**EDIT:** XML Added

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Header>
    <OGHeader transactionID="005435" timeStamp="2008-12-09T13:26:56.4056250-05:00" xmlns="http://webservices.micros.com/og/4.3/Core/">
      <Origin entityID="OWS" systemType="WEB" />
      <Destination entityID="WEST" systemType="ORS" />
    </OGHeader>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <FetchCalendarRequest xmlns:a="http://webservices.micros.com/og/4.3/Availability/" xmlns:hc="http://webservices.micros.com/og/4.3/HotelCommon/" xmlns="http://webservices.micros.com/ows/5.1/Availability.wsdl">
      <HotelReference chainCode="AXA" hotelCode="AXAMUM" />
      <StayDateRange>
        <hc:StartDate>2013-10-01</hc:StartDate>
        <hc:EndDate>2013-10-10</hc:EndDate>
      </StayDateRange>
      <GuestCount>
        <hc:GuestCount ageQualifyingCode="ADULT" count="1" />
        <hc:GuestCount ageQualifyingCode="CHILD" count="0" />
      </GuestCount>
    </FetchCalendarRequest>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Did you tried to get the functions list with `var_dump($client->__getFunctions());` to see it the `FetchCalendar` function is even available. Also make sure you are using right params, both for headers and called function

Comment: i have changed code `$client = new SoapClient('http://webservices.micros.com/ows/5.1/Availability.wsdl');` now its says :  _'SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'HotelReference' property'_

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are 2 layer of problem, first you didn't catch the exception when it is thrown. second you request might be incorrect/invalid that's why it returns 400 bad request

```
try{
      $client->__soapCall("FetchCalendar", $para);
}catch (SoapFault $exception){
      //or any other handling you like
      var_dump(get_class($exception));
      var_dump($exception);
}
```

Comment: you have a slight error in your code `{catch (SoapFault $exception){` instead of `} catch (SoapFault $exception){`

Comment: i have added XML request to be send.

Comment: i have changed code `$client = new SoapClient('http://webservices.micros.com/ows/5.1/Availability.wsdl');` now its says : _'SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'HotelReference' property' _

Comment: The method your trying to run needs a HotelReference. I guess it needs the HotelReference so it can check in the calendar for that Hotel. Download SoapUI, this is free software and will make your live easier when using soap. You will be able to browse trough all the methods and see what options / variables they require.

Comment: `<HotelReference chainCode="AXA" hotelCode="AXAMUM" />` you are correct ! but i know how to pass parameter like staydaterange, dont know how to pass property? check xml.

Comment: about passing property, it's some thing that I believe you can (and you should) learn on your own. Pay a visit to the manual page and everything you need will be there.
(http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php)